# How can I check whether this window handle is for the splash window or for the real main window of the application

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi

I'm building [a small library](https://github.com/andrewchaa/PopOpen) that pushing a process' window to the foreground, by using user32.dll's SetWindowPos and GetWindowRect. The code finds a MainWindowHandle of a process and make it modal and then non-modal, so that the window appears in the foreground.

One problem I encountered is the splash screen. For example, when MS Word first opens, it shows the splash screen. then process.MainWindowHandle returns a handle to the splash screen. A few seconds later, it's gone and the actual main window of MS Word appears and process.MainWindowHandle returns another handle to that window.

I wonder if there's a way I can check if the handle is for Splash screen or not.
Of course, I can wait for a certain time, say 15 seconds, if the window handle changes and if it does, push it to the foreground again. But it'd awesome to figure out if it's a handle for splash screen.

Comment: I can think of a few tricks, such as checking whether the window appears in the taskbar (splash screens usually don't), but it really depends on the implementation of each app... I don't believe it's possible to find a generic solution working with every case. In the end, a splash screen is just an ordinary window.

Comment: Another issue is that it's unclear exactly what counts as a splash screen. What about a dialog "First time initialization - please wait while we create a widget database [====------]" ?